# Change individual x-axis labels on faceted grouped bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, facet-grid

I'm trying to adjust each individual x-axis label by adding an annotation.

I'm able to adjust the first two labels, but the next 6 just repeat those first two, instead of taking on their own individual labels (the numbers should be different).

Here's the `scale_x_discrete` part of my ggplot script:

```
 scale_x_discrete(
    
    # Change x group labels
    labels = c(
      paste0("PPA\n(", comma(PPA_LA_2019, digits = 0), "\ntotal)"), 
      paste0("Non-PPA\n(", comma(non_PPA_LA_2019, digits = 0), "\ntotal)"),
      paste0("PPA\n(", comma(PPA_LA_2020, digits = 0), "\ntotal)"), 
      paste0("Non-PPA\n(", comma(non_PPA_LA_2020, digits = 0), "\ntotal)"),
      paste0("PPA\n(", comma(PPA_LA_2021, digits = 0), "\ntotal)"), 
      paste0("Non-PPA\n(", comma(non_PPA_LA_2021, digits = 0), "\ntotal)"),
      paste0("PPA\n(", comma(PPA_LA_2022, digits = 0), "\ntotal)"), 
      paste0("Non-PPA\n(", comma(non_PPA_LA_2022, digits = 0), "\ntotal)")
      )
  ) +
```

Here are the values I want to be showing up across the x-axis:
[x-axis label values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxnhz.png)

And here's what I'm getting:
[current x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMB7v.png)

Comment: That will not work. As your axis has only two breaks per panel only the first two labels will be used. Instead try with mapping `paste0(prior_status, "\n(", comma(n, digits = 0), "\ntotal)")` on `x` and use `scales="free_x"` in facet_grid/wrap. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a working code example and a snippet of your data or some fake data.